# update_all clear my array in variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My small service in Rails

```
class ReadUserService
  def self.read_users(count)
    users = Users.inactive.limit(count)

    users.update_all(status: User.statuses[:active])

    users.to_a
  end
end
```

When I not call `update_all`, `users` variable is correctly, but When I use `update_all`, my `users` variable is empty. How Can I stopped clear my array? I need return all users from db, which have inactive status before `update_all`

Comment: I think `update_all` returns the count of no of record updated.

Comment: try to replace this `users.update_all(status: User.statuses[:active])` with `Users.inactive.limit(count).update_all(status: User.statuses[:active])` I hope this will work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all):

> Updates all records in the current relation with details given. This method constructs a single `SQL UPDATE` statement and sends it straight to the database. It **does not instantiate the involved models** and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. Values passed to `update_all` will not go through ActiveRecord's type-casting behavior. It should receive only values that can be passed as-is to the SQL database.

As I highlighted: `update_all` does not load and instantiate the object in the relation. That means the `users` variable just holds a relation object but has not queried the database for matching records. The first time the relation tries to load records is in `users.to_a`. But at that point in time the record has already been changed (made active).

To fix this, load the record first and update them later:

```
def self.read_users(count)
  scope = Users.inactive.limit(count)
  users = scope.to_a

  scope.update_all(status: User.statuses[:active])

  users
end
```

Comment: @WandMaker: No, `update_all` is method on an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html), but `users` is an array.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

`@spickermann`'s answer is correct.

However, to make it more simplistic, it looks like [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) is a class method (IE invokes the class), which suggests you should be calling it when you initialize the class (not afterwards, as an instance method):

```
class ReadUserService
  def self.read_users(count)
     User.inactive.limit(count).update_all(status: User.statuses[:active]) #-> this will be returned by default
  end
end
```

If you wanted to make it more eloquent, use `@spickermann`'s suggestion.